# Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation with cakePHP

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp

I am using the framework cakePHP for my application. I programmed it on localhost with xampp and try to upload it on my website now. It worked without any problems on localhost. Now there is only this one page, which does not work on the new server. The other sites (which use the database connection too) work alright.

For this one site the following message appears:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'add' at line 1
>
> SQL Query: add

The function add() looks like this.

```
public function add() { 
      //$this->create();
      $word_id = $this->Word->getWord_id();
      $save = $this->save(array('word_id' => $word_id, 'text' => $this->getText($word_id), 'mistake' => 0));
      return $save['Game']['id']; 
   }
```

On localhost I used MySQL-Client-Version: mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Revision: 310735 $ and PHP Version 5.3.8.

On the server I use MySQL-Client-Version: 5.1.62 and PHP Version 5.3.17.

Thank you very much for helping!

Edit:
The model 'Game':

```
class Game extends AppModel {
   public $name = 'Game';
   public $belongsTo = 'Word';
   public $searchedWord = '';

   public function addGame() { // Create new game
      $word_id = $this->Word->getWord_id();
      $save = $this->save(array('word_id' => $word_id, 'text' => $this->getText($word_id), 'mistake' => 0));
      return $save['Game']['id']; // Build the hangman
    }
}
```

When I debug $this->Game, the output is:

```
object(AppModel) {
        useDbConfig => 'default'
        useTable => 'games'
        id => null
        data => array()
        schemaName => null
        table => 'games'
        primaryKey => 'id'
        validate => array()
        validationErrors => array()
        validationDomain => null
        name => 'Game'
        alias => 'Game'
        tableToModel => array(
            'games' => 'Game'
        )
        cacheQueries => false
        belongsTo => array()
        hasOne => array()
        hasMany => array()
        hasAndBelongsToMany => array()
        actsAs => null
        Behaviors => object(BehaviorCollection) {
            modelName => 'Game'
            defaultPriority => (int) 10
        }
        whitelist => array()
        cacheSources => true
        findQueryType => null
        recursive => (int) 1
        order => null
        virtualFields => array()
        __backAssociation => array()
        __backInnerAssociation => array()
        __backOriginalAssociation => array()
        __backContainableAssociation => array()
        findMethods => array(
            'all' => true,
            'first' => true,
            'count' => true,
            'neighbors' => true,
            'list' => true,
            'threaded' => true
        )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

usually, if this error happens, you don't have the model instance, but an app model instance you work on. the app model instance doesnt have the add() method and directly queries the db with add().

so make sure your model is properly included. since you didnt show us the code how you call the method (and how you make the model available to the controller) I cannot offer any concrete advice, though.

if you manually include it:

```
$this->ModelName = ClassRegistry::init('ModelName');
```

Comment: The method call in the controller looks like this:

    class GamesController extends AppController {
        public $name = 'Game';
        public function index($gameid = null, $letter = null) {
          if ($gameid == null) { // New game
             $gameid = $this->Game->addGame();
          }
    }


If the model isn't included, how can it work locally? :/

Comment: following conventions cake will load the model to the controller (Game for GamesController). so far so good. but maybe your model is defined wrong? you should post the model code. also `debug($this->Game)` and tell us the results.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i added this information to my question.

Comment: as I said, Its an AppModel instance. maybe your file is located at the wrong folder? either way cake doesnt find it and creates the tmp-model.

Comment: My folder structure looks like this:
app/
- Controller/
-- AppController.php
-- GamesController.php
- Model/
-- AppModel.php
-- game.php

I don't know where I don't use the conventions.. :/
I use cakePHP version 2.2.2.

Comment: Game.php for instance (note the capital C!). please consult the manual for the conventions.

Comment: This was the problem.. i'm sorry. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

**add** is a reserved word in MySQL and you're probably using it in a SQL query without "escape".

Check if you have any field named **add** in your database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I changed the function name in "addGame", but the error is still there. 
There is no field named 'add' in my database.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this error and I felt pretty stupid. I'm sure this has been solved a long time ago, but in case anyone else comes across it...

Using your example I'll show basically what I also stupidly did in my Controller and how it caused the same type of error you had:

```
 public function index($gameid = null, $letter = null) {
      if ($gameid == null) {
           // New game
           $gameid = $this->Game->addGame();
      }
 }
```

Since you already have the instance (controller class) and you're not calling the Model method of `addGame` here, but the Controller's method, you simply remove the `Game->` from your one-line command.

```
 $gameid = $this->addGame();
```

Simple and easy oversight. That said, if you moved the addGame method to your Model class, it probably would have worked as expected. :)