# Cakephp throws Syntax error or access violation error

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm following this [tutorial](http://florian-kraemer.net/2015/10/cakephp-angularjs-pagination/) and i'm trying to create pagination with cakephp 2.9.2 and AngularJs1.5. The problem is that when i add this tutorial code, i'm keep getting error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation.

This is my controller

```
/**
 * Todos Controller
 */
class TodosController extends AppController
{
    public $components = array('RequestHandler', 'Paginator');

    /**
     * Index
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->Paginator->settings = array(
            'limit' => 5,
            'order' => array(
                'todo.todo_id' => 'asc'
            )
        );
        if (empty($this->request->params['paging'][$this->Todo->alias()])) {
            $paging = false;
        } else {
            $paging = $this->request->params['paging'][$this->Todo->alias()];
        }
        $this->set('Todos', $this->Paginator->paginate('Todo'));
        $this->set('paging', $paging);
        $this->set('_serialize', ['Todos', 'paging']);
    }
```

Model

```
   class Todo extends AppModel {

        public $primaryKey = 'todo_id';

        public $validate = array(
            'title' => array(
                'notBlank' => array(
                    'rule' => array('notBlank'),
                ),
            ),
            'user' => array(
                'notBlank' => array(
                    'rule' => array('notBlank'),
                ),
            ),
            'description' => array(
                'notBlank' => array(
                    'rule' => array('notBlank'),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
```

And once i visit myapp.com/rest/todos this is error i'm geting

```
{
    "code": 500,
    "name": "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near &#039;alias&#039; at line 1",
    "message": "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near &#039;alias&#039; at line 1",
    "url": "\/rest\/todos",
    "error": {
        "errorInfo": [
            "42000",
            1064,
            "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'alias' at line 1"
        ],
        "queryString": "alias"
    }
}
```

Can some one please explain me what i'm doing wrong. Meybe tutorial is written in cakephp3 and i'm using cakephp2.9.2? What is the simplest way to achieve desired effect in my current cakephp version?

If you need any additional information's, please let me know and i will provide. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you post the code in your model(Todo)? You clearly have a problem with the sql, check for quotations and commas etc near alias

Comment: `"queryString": "alias"`   `alias` is no real sql query, where is the sql created?

Comment: @ArrowHead Model code is added

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions... I realy don't know since i was just following that tutorial

Comment: OK, but im not so into cakephp so i cant help, i only noticed the not correct setup query in your error message

Comment: There is no `Model::alias()` method in CakePHP 2.x, there only is a property with that name. That blog post is referring to CakePHP 3.x.

Comment: check out similar problem here. Since you modifying and existing tutorial code. check out the spellings well.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653879/error-sqlstate42000-syntax-error-or-access-violation-with-cakephp?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least you are not using that alias property correctly, Try this instead:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'limit' => 5,
        'order' => array(
            'todo.todo_id' => 'asc'
        )
    );

    $this->set('Todos', $this->Paginator->paginate('Todo'));

    if (isset($this->request->params['paging']) && !empty($this->request->params['paging'])) {
        $paging = $this->request->params['paging']['Todo']; // or simply $paging = $this->request->params['paging']; // depending upon your logic
    } else {
        $paging = false;
    }

    $this->set('paging', $paging);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['Todos', 'paging']);
}
```